# How to preload iframe urls on Ionic

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, iframe, ionic2

I'm using iframe links on Ionic 3 app. I found when I open up a page with an iframe link, it doesn't load a site quickly. 
Iframe will display a white blank loading screen for 3 seconds before actually loading a page. 
Is there any way to preload all links on app's initialization so I can bypass iframe loading time? 
I hope there's a way.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could simply keep the iframe hidden or outside the viewable area while loading contents, then show it when it has finished loading using the `onload` event.

Using jQuery:

```
$('#the_iframe').load(function(){
    /* Loaded done, show it now */
    $('#the_iframe').show();
});
```

I haven't tested it on a hidden iframe, if it doesn't work simply send it off-canvas then reposition it properly to show it.